# from(promise) observable map down to deeper field which is an array and use in html, angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, contentful

I was following this video on youtube about contentful for angular, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2agJoqviGY4&t=341s

He uses `<section *ngIf="landingContent$ | async as content">` in the html template, I would like to go deeper in the landingContent$ variable, to be like `<section *ngIf="landingContent$.landingTemplate.content[0].data.target.fields | async as content">`, but this throws errors.

Component:

```
export class HeroHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  landingContent$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(public contentful: ContentfulService) {}    
ngOnInit() {
        this.landingContent$ = this.contentful.getContent("xxx");
      }
```

Service:

```
getContent(contentId) {
    const promise = this.client.getEntry(contentId);
    return from(promise).pipe(
      map((entry) => entry.fields.landingTemplate.content[0].data.target.fields)
    );
  }
```

Here in the service I get an TS error saying `"Property 'landingTemplate' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts"` However if I just use `map((entry) => entry.fields` I get no errors but then can't find a way to go deeper to get the `landingContent$` to something like `landingContent$.landingTemplate.content[0].data.target.fields` elsewhere. I have made a hackie fix where I subscribe on the component and create a variable that then returns this field, but I would have liked to have used the elegant `| async as content` method in the html, if possible.

Html:

```
<section class="why" id="section-why" *ngIf="landingContent$ | async as content">
  <div class="layout-grid">
    <h2 class="title">{{ content.heading }}</h2>
```

Comment: try double dot .. instead of single dot
entry.fields..landingTemplate.content[0].data.target.fields) and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If the TypeScript typings just aren't right for contentful, and those properties really exist at runtime, you can always use RxJS `pluck()` to drill down in your service.

```
getContent(contentId) {
    return from(this.client.getEntry(contentId)).pipe(
      pluck('fields', 'landingTemplate', 'content[0]', 'data', 'target', 'fields')
    );
  }
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/pluck